# how to create rounded corners in svg

Tags: html, css, svg

I'd like to create rounder corners for my svg path but I can't make it work.
Is there a good way to accomplish this? here is my code:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%">
  <clipPath id="svgClip">
  <path id="svgPath" d="M3,474 L957,471 942,24 40,1 z" />
  </clipPath>
  <path id="svgMask" d="M3,474 L957,471 942,24 40,1 z" />
</svg>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `stroke-linejoin="round"` and pick a suitable `stroke-width`.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="300" height="300" viewBox="-100 -100 1200 1000">
  <path id="svgMask" d="M3,474 L957,471 942,24 40,1 z" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke="black" stroke-width="80"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic or easy way to do this for paths.  You can supply an `r` (radius) attribute to`<rect>` elements, but there is no equivalent for `<path>`.

You would need to calculate and add cubic bezier path commands (`C` or `c`) at the appropriate places in your path.

Comment: Not quite.  Your answer just described how to make bezier curves, but didn't explain why.

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on compatibility but [stroke-linecap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/svg/attribute/stroke-linecap) works in Chromium browsers.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%">
  <clipPath id="svgClip">
  <path id="svgPath" d="M3,474 L957,471 942,24 40,1 z" stroke-linecap="round"/>
  </clipPath>
  <path id="svgMask" d="M3,474 L957,471 942,24 40,1 z" stroke-linecap="round"/>
</svg>
```